# What does the Foursquare venues/search return?

Tags: search, return, foursquare

Does anyone know what the Foursquare venues/search return? Does it give the up-to-date Foursquare venues or all the venues ever created for an area? I read this page https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/venues/search but it was not that specific. It goes like: "Returns a list of venues near the current location, optionally matching a search term". Does anyone have more information about this?

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, the search request doesn't distinguish user created places like "Joe Bob's House" from a business like "Starbucks." It returns all of the nearby places best matched to this particular user if the intent is to checkin, or all of the nearby places if the intent is to browse for "coffee," for example.

Does that answer your question?

Comment: Thanks! It does partly. What does the intent checkin (default value) return then? The explanation says: "Finds results that the current user (or, for userless requests, a typical user) is likely to check in to at the provided ll at the current moment in time". What does it mean "likely"? Am I obtaining the actual Foursquare dataset or just some venues based on some sort of likeliness algorithm?

Comment: @user3480660 I don't work for Foursquare, but it seems likely that they have some sort of algorithm when returning results for an authenticated user. Theoretically it could be based on not just previous checkins, but also time of day, friends checkins (nearby or historical), likes of other people's checkins, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You should take a closer look at the `intent` parameter on that page. You can specify the type of results you're looking for. Depending on your needs, you might also want to check out [venues/explore](https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/venues/explore)